# How do I add a new username and password to a database list (i have a pass file an a username file

Tags: linux, bash, passwords

## !/bin/bash

I am working on something for school for my linux class. i am trying to make a script that will log your username and send it to "users2". also the password that will go to "passwords2".

```
echo -n "username:" read | user2
echo -n "password:" read | password2
```

I have tried everything I can think of if you can help me I would love that.
thank you,
zack

Answer (score 0):

To redirect output from the screen to a file, you can use `>`, or `>>` to append, for example

```
 echo "Some text" > file.txt
 echo "Some other text" >> file.txt
```

will result in

```
$ cat file.txt 
Some text
Some other text
```

To store user input to a variable, say `input`, use `read input`.

Other than that, you are missing a semicolon between the two commands `echo ...` and `read` (or put them on separate lines).

A minimal example for a script, which appends user input to a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Input: "; read input
echo $input >> file.txt
```